# Adding php variable to button value

Tags: php

I have a php variable ($num_rows) that i want to add to button value.

I am not getting value i want which should show like "Pending Friend Requests(0)"

I tried many different things but is not working. How can i write the code so that i get right value?

Here is the code:

```
$interactionBox= '<input type="button" value="Pending Friend Requests(\'.$num_rows.\')" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:toggleInteractContainers(\'friend_requests\');"/>';
```

I tried:

```
value="Pending Friend Requests(".$num_rows.")"
value="Pending Friend Requests(.".$num_rows.".)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the backslashes before the single quotes for the variable to be included like so:

```
$interactionBox= '<input type="button" value="Pending Friend Requests('.$num_rows.')" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:toggleInteractContainers(\'friend_requests\');"/>';
```

Answer (score 1):

There's something wrong with your escaped `'` around the values.

Do it this way:
$variable = "parsed string, so the variable name can be inside the string $num_rows";
$variable = 'This is a static string so the variables have to be appended, e.g. ' . $num_rows . ', to work.';

Escaped quote characters (`\"` or `\'`) are treted as if they'd be any other standard character inside the string.

Answer (score 0):

just try this one
`value="Pending Friend Requests('.$num_rows.')"`
no need to escape single quotes within double quotes